# WireAdmin Service Not Registered

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

I have the following activator intended to use the wireAdmin Service from the OSGI framework. This is the start method of the activator.

```
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Hashtable props = new Hashtable<>();
        props.put("service.pid", "consumer.service");
        props.put(WireConstants.WIREADMIN_CONSUMER_FLAVORS,
                new Class [] {Object.class});
        ServiceRegistration reg = context.registerService(WireConsumer.
                                     class.getName(), this, props);
        ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(
                                         WireAdmin.class.getName());
        WireAdmin wa = (WireAdmin) context.getService(ref);
        Wire wire = wa.createWire("producerwire.service",
                             "consumer.service", new Hashtable<>());
    }
```

What I have done is tried to use the WireAdmin Service from the framework. The problem is I get a NullPointer Exception, because no WireAdmin Service is present in the framework. The have used the following bundle for WireAdmin service. org.osgi.service.wireadmin, which is not registering any service to framework. So, I guess my question is which is the bundle to use if we are to get a reference of wireadmin service from the framework?

Comment: Version              1.0.1.201505202024
RegisteredServices   null
ServicesInUse        null
BundleContext        org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl@6876fa77
SymbolicName         org.osgi.service.wireadmin
**Information about org.osgi.service.wireadmin bundle**

Comment: Ok. I found an implementation by the equinox framework, again the bundle is not registering any services, any help would be greatly appriciated. The bundle I am running now is **org.eclipse.equinox.wireadmin**, this again fails to register a wire admin service.